# Ignore lines running debuggers like pdb.set_trace() or debugger in the repository?

Tags: javascript, python, git

Sometimes when I commit my code in python or javascript, I forgot to remove the debuggers, so I must do it manually.

I know something about creating a .gitattributes file at the root of the project with the following code:

`*.py filter=import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

`*.js filter=debugger`

But when I commit the code, it saves the lines in the repository anyway.

How to remove or at least comment these lines in the repository, and put them back in the working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting the unwanted lines out, in js this is done by putting the // operator before unwanted lines.
In python this is done by the # operator before the unwanted line
for instance

```
#filter=import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

And for js

```
//filter=debugger
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But is there a way to comment all lines, and commit them without doing manually?

Answer (score 0):

Opinion: the `filter` option in a `.gitattributes` should not be used the way you're trying to use it.  Even if you fix the syntax, this is a bad idea.

---

The actual problem is that the syntax for `filter` lines in `.gitattributes` is simply:

```
filter=<name>
```

You must then *define* this filter (one whose *`name`* you substitute in for the angle bracketed expression) in `.git/config` or your global `.gitconfig`.  For instance, if you had a filter named `hack-debug-lines-in-python`, you might have:

```
*.py filter=hack-debug-lines-in-python
```

in the `.gitattributes` file, and then:

```
[filter "hack-debug-lines-in-python"]
    clean = ...
    smudge = ...
```

in your `.git/config`.  You would need to fill in the three dots here with an actual *program* that can do the debug-line trickiness that you want.

You will need to write this filter program.  Git does not include one.